# Attribute Error: Sideways shooter object has not attribute! Python Crash Course 2nd Edition

Tags: python, pygame

New to Python and have left myself stumped for a few hours. I am trying to follow the examples in the book Python Crash Course. Im at the last part of trying to make bullets shoot across the screen but i come with the `AttributeError` when trying to define the limits of the game screen the bullet can travel before being deleted, in the '_update_bullets' method. I have tried using `self.screen_rect` but that also brings up an `AttributeError`.

```
import sys
import pygame
from gun import Gun
from bullets import Bullet

class SidewaysShooter:
    #Game board

    def __init__(self):
        #Initializes game and resources.
        pygame.init()


        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 500))
        pygame.display.set_caption("Sideways Shooter")


        self.gun = Gun(self)
        self.bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()

        #set background color
        self.bg_color = (153, 72, 141)

    def run_game(self):
        #Start the main loop for the game
        while True:
            self._check_events()
            self.gun.update ()
            self._update_bullets()
            self._update_screen()

    def _check_events(self):
        #Watch for keyboard and mounse events.
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                self._check_keydown_events(event)
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                self._check_keyup_events(event)

    def _check_keydown_events(self, event):
        if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            self.gun.moving_up = True
        elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            self.gun.moving_down = True
        elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
            self._fire_bullet()
        elif event.key == pygame.K_q:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    def _check_keyup_events(self, event):
        if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            self.gun.moving_up = False
        if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            self.gun.moving_down = False

    def _fire_bullet(self):
        """Create a new bullet and add it to the bullets group."""
        new_bullet = Bullet(self)
        self.bullets.add(new_bullet)

    def _update_bullets(self):
        """Update the position of the bullets and get rid of old bullets."""
        #Update bullets position
        self.bullets.update()

        #Get rid of bullets that have disappeared.
        for bullet in self.bullets.copy():
            if bullet.rect.left >= self.screen_right:
                self.bullets.remove(bullet)


    def _update_screen(self):
        #Update images on a screen and flip to a new screen
        self.screen.fill(self.bg_color)
        self.gun.blitme()
        for bullet in self.bullets.sprites():
            bullet.draw_bullet()


        pygame.display.flip()

if __name__== '__main__':
    #MAke a game instance, and run the game.
    ai = SidewaysShooter()
    ai.run_game()
```

'''

Comment: Please add the full error message (you can elide the stack trace if it is long).

Comment: '''
Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\Antho\Desktop\python_work\python37\shooter\sideways_shooter.py", line 89, in <module> ai.run_game() File "C:\Users\Antho\Desktop\python_work\python37\shooter\sideways_shooter.py", line 29, in run_game self._update_bullets() File "C:\Users\Antho\Desktop\python_work\python37\shooter\sideways_shooter.py", line 72, in _update_bullets if bullet.rect.left >= self.screen_right: AttributeError: 'SidewaysShooter' object has no attribute 'screen_right''''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the attribute error because there is no "**screen_right**"-Attribute defined (in your example).
You need to inizialize it as a Int, to have access to it in all of the objects functions it needs to be in your "**__init__(self)**" function.

Example:

```
def __init__(self):
    #Initializes game and resources.
    pygame.init()
    self.display_width = 1200  # The size of the screen should be defined
    self.display_height = 500  # Now you can use it when you create the screen.
    self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.display_width, self.display_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Sideways Shooter")
    self.gun = Gun(self)
    self.bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()
    #set background color
    self.bg_color = (153, 72, 141)
    self.screen_right = self.display_width  # This is the position of the right side of the screen, 0 would be the left side
```